# HornetQ throws server - HQ224045: Failed to run large message deliverer

Tags: hornetq

There are a  few thousand messages just sitting under `largemessages` directory. They are not delivered, and I presume because of this exception

We are using embedded HornetQ version 2.4.1.Final

I found these stack traces:

```
ERROR [Thread-9 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=228d6abf-6f78-11e5-9476-ab4e397e2e52-1420470414)]: server - HQ224045: Failed to run large message deliverer
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:994)
        at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl$LargeMessageDeliverer.deliver(ServerConsumerImpl.java:1090)
        at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl$2.run(ServerConsumerImpl.java:969)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and this one:

```
2015-12-29 03:02:02,658 ERROR [Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-2138527112)]: client - HQ124003: Message Listener failed to prepare message for receipt
HornetQLargeMessageException[errorType=LARGE_MESSAGE_ERROR_BODY message=HQ119028: Timeout waiting for LargeMessage Body]
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.waitCompletion(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:372)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.saveBuffer(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:319)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.checkBuffer(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:186)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.checkCompletion(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:89)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessage.doBeforeReceive(HornetQMessage.java:968)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTextMessage.doBeforeReceive(HornetQTextMessage.java:129)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:79)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1116)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:56)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1251)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Help is much appreciated.